# How do i insert multiple rows to a specific postmeta

Tags: sql, wordpress

I am trying update multiple wordpress postmeta fields in one query.

Fields

```
  $fields = [
            'token'       => $car_hash, 
            'historie'    => $car_history,
            'korrekt'     => $car_correct, 
            'kilometer'   => $car_km,
            'brand'       => $car_brand,
            'model'       => $car_model,
            'post_nummer' => $user_zip, 
            'navn'        => $user_name, 
            'telefon'     => $user_phone, 
            'email'       => $user_mail,
            'datetime'    => $user_datetime,
            'customer_city' => $city,
            'customer_country' => $country,
            'customer_lat' => $lattitude,
            'customer_lng' => $longitude
          ];
```

Old code which execute a query by using the key value pair in the fields array above.

```
foreach($fields as $key => $value){
    update_field($key, $value, $id);
}
```

I have been trying to use [wpdb::update](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/update/) but i think i am misunderstanding something.

```
  $fields = [
            'token'       => $car_hash, 
            'historie'    => $car_history,
            'korrekt'     => $car_correct, 
            'kilometer'   => $car_km,
            'brand'       => $car_brand,
            'model'       => $car_model,
            'post_nummer' => $user_zip, 
            'navn'        => $user_name, 
            'telefon'     => $user_phone, 
            'email'       => $user_mail,
            'datetime'    => $user_datetime,
            'customer_city' => $city,
            'customer_country' => $country,
            'customer_lat' => $lattitude,
            'customer_lng' => $longitude
          ];

  $tab = 'solgt_postmeta';
  $len = count($fields);
  $arg = [];
  $for = [];

  foreach($fields as $key => $value){
    $arg[$key] = $value;
    $for[] = '%s';
    $cnt++;
  }

  global $wpdb;

  if($wpdb->update($tab, $arg, $for)){
    echo 'success';
  } else {
    echo 'error';
  }
```

The formats array look like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => %s
    [1] => %s
    [2] => %s
    [3] => %s
    [4] => %s
    [5] => %s
    [6] => %s
    [7] => %s
    [8] => %s
    [9] => %s
    [10] => %s
    [11] => %s
    [12] => %s
    [13] => %s
    [14] => %s
);
```

The arguments array look like this

```
Array
(
    [token] => xxx
    [historie] => xxx
    [korrekt] => xxx
    [kilometer] => xxx
    [brand] => xxx
    [model] => xxx
    [post_nummer] => xxx
    [navn] => xxx
    [telefon] => xxx
    [email] => xxx
    [datetime] => xxx
    [customer_city] => xxx
    [customer_country] => xxx
    [customer_lat] => xxx
    [customer_lng] => xxx
);
```

I dont normally use wordpress, and i am confused on how to achieve this without having to do so many queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [update_post_meta()](https://codex.wordpress.org/update_post_meta) instead of `wpdb::update`

```php
<?php 
  update_post_meta( <post_id>, 
             'token'      , $car_hash, 
            'historie'    , $car_history,
            'korrekt'     , $car_correct, 
            'kilometer'   , $car_km,
            'brand'       , $car_brand,
            'model'       , $car_model,
            'post_nummer' , $user_zip, 
            'navn'        , $user_name, 
            'telefon'     , $user_phone, 
            'email'       , $user_mail,
            'datetime'    , $user_datetime,
            'customer_city' , $city,
            'customer_country' , $country,
            'customer_lat' , $lattitude,
            'customer_lng' , $longitude
  );
```